# Load more than one page - Infinite Scroll JS

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, infinite

I would like to load more than only on page using [infinitescroll.js.](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Script:

```
$('.wrapper').infinitescroll({

navSelector  : '#page-nav',            
   // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : '#page-nav a',    
   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : '.page'          
   // selector for all items you'll retrieve
});
```

Page 1:

```
<h2>Graffiti</h2>

<ul class="page">
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/1.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/2.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/3.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/4.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/4.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/5.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/5.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/6.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/6.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/7.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/7.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/8.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/8.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/9.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/9.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/10.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/10.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/11.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/11.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/12.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/12.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>

<nav id="page-nav">
    <a href="?page=graffiti/graffiti2"></a>
</nav>
```

Page 2:

```
<h2>Graffiti</h2>

<ul class="page">
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/13.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/13.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/14.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/14.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/15.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/15.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/16.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/16.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/17.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/17.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/18.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/18.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/19.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/19.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/20.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/20.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/21.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/21.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/22.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/22.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/23.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/23.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="assets/img/graffiti/24.jpg" rel="lightbox[graffiti]"><img src="assets/img/graffiti/thumbs/24.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>


<nav id="page-nav">
<a href="?page=graffiti/graffiti3"></a>
</nav>
```

etc. But the plugin only loads the first page.

How do I have to chage the markup to load more than just one page?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just increase the limit of resources fetched from the server? Instead of 12 elements per page, you get 24, those are technically the 2 pages you want, right?

Comment: I actually have 6 pages in total.

Comment: that'd be then 3 pages of 24 elements each.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why having 24 lements each page should help me here. My problem is that only the second page is loaded by infinitescroll.js and the others do not load at all.